# Personal Photo in App About Page

Tags: iphone, iphone-developer-program

I have an app that has an about page.  I would really like to include a photo of myself, mostly to boast to my friends.  I am under 18 however my parents are the ones that have the developer account, so it would basically be them putting my picture up with my consent.  I was wondering if Apple will reject my app because of the person photo or not.

Thanks, Michael Amici

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official App Store Review Guidelines state nothing that will reject your app because you didn't buy the developer account yourself. Company's that have multiple employees won't get their apps rejected either because the person who bought the developer account actually programmed the app. If you have the consent it should be no problem.

The bottomline is: If you coded the app yourself and you have the consent from the owners of the Developer Account to release that app under their account they cant reject it for that reason.

Comment: Also, there was a big story last year about a very young boy making an iPhone game, so as long as the parents are the ones signing off on the agreements with Apple, I cannot see them finding a problem here (as long as the picture is reasonable, better put on a shirt ;-)